# Getting Django model.index has no field problem (django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist)

Tags: django

I am trying to create an index.The problem is that I am getting no 'has no field' error but I added that field. I tried to add that field  but I got "column "click_count" of relation "oyunlar" already exists". How can i solve this situation?
This my model:

```
game_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    youtube_link=models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
    video_aciklamasi=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    release_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    click_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    categories=models.ManyToManyField(Kategoriler,through='OyunlarKategoriler')
    base_price=models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=65535, decimal_places=2)
    big_discount=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    en_ucuz = models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=65535, decimal_places=2)
    popularite = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,default=0)
    discount_rate = models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=65535, decimal_places=2)
    title_edit = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100000, blank=True, null=True)
    steam_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    metacritic = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    recommendation = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    full_game = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    minimum = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)
    recommended = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    oyun_foto = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True),blank=True,null=True) # This field type is a guess.
    windows = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    mac = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    linux = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    gamehunterz_yorumu = models.CharField(max_length=100000, blank=True, null=True)
    slugyap = AutoSlugField(default=None,null=True,populate_from='title_and_id',editable=True,max_length=10000)
    platformurl=AutoSlugField(default=None,null=True,editable=True,max_length=10000)
    hashtags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True), blank=True, null=True)
    mobil_photo=models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    mobil_photo_array = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True),blank=True,null=True)
    dlc=models.BooleanField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    fullgameid=models.IntegerField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)# This field type is a guess.

class Meta:
    managed = True
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['platform', '-click_count' ]),
    ]
    db_table = 'oyunlar'
```

This is my migration code:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    
        dependencies = [
            ('games', '0050_auto_20211206_1505'),
        ]
    
        operations = [
    
    
            migrations.AddIndex(
                model_name='oyunlar',
                index=models.Index(fields=['platform', '-click_count'], name='oyunlar_platfor_d93c5d_idx'),
            ),
        ]
```

Comment: Please show us the code in question.

Comment: I edited the question you can see the code.

Comment: Can you also add the actual error and command you type to migrate?